# Exclude all send from one particular email of journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I came across a need of exclusion script which can exclude all the email send from one particular email of a journey. if I just add "1" in the exclusion script does it exclude all the email send from that particular email activity of journey ?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution is to make an exclusion script on it like so:

`1 == 1`

And that should exclude it for all as it will always equate to true.

Comment: Is 1==1 really the easiest solution? For some people that do not like odd numbers 2==2 would be way better. Upvote Gortoningtons answer, it deserves more than 100 upvotes ;) Because it is just sharp as a knife and very precise